# Can't compile the ACE 6.3.0 library apps in CentOS 6.5

Tags: linux, centos6, ace

After ungzip-tar, the configure and the make in objdir succeeded. Trying to do a make in the gperf directory under apps fails with below :

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/apps/drwho'
/home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/include/makeinclude/wrapper_macros.GNU:218: /home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/include/makeinclude/platform_macros.GNU: No such file or directory
/home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/bin/add_rel_link.sh /home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/apps/drwho/platform_macros.GNU /home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/include/makeinclude/platform_macros.GNU
ln -s ../../apps/drwho/platform_macros.GNU /home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/include/makeinclude/platform_macros.GNU
drwho__client will not be built due to the following missing library: ACE

GNUmakefile: /home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/apps/drwho/GNUmakefile.drwho__client MAKEFLAGS=w

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/apps/drwho'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/apps/drwho'
/home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/include/makeinclude/wrapper_macros.GNU:218: /home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/include/makeinclude/platform_macros.GNU: No such file or directory
/home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/bin/add_rel_link.sh /home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/apps/drwho/platform_macros.GNU /home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/include/makeinclude/platform_macros.GNU
ln -s ../../apps/drwho/platform_macros.GNU /home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/include/makeinclude/platform_macros.GNU
drwho__server will not be built due to the following missing library: ACE

GNUmakefile: /home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/apps/drwho/GNUmakefile.drwho__server MAKEFLAGS=w

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/apps/drwho'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/apps/gperf'
/home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/include/makeinclude/wrapper_macros.GNU:218: /home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/include/makeinclude/platform_macros.GNU: No such file or directory
/home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/bin/add_rel_link.sh /home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/apps/gperf/platform_macros.GNU /home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/include/makeinclude/platform_macros.GNU
ln -s ../../apps/gperf/platform_macros.GNU /home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/include/makeinclude/platform_macros.GNU

GNUmakefile: /home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/apps/gperf/GNUmakefile.gperf_docs MAKEFLAGS=w

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/apps/gperf'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/apps/gperf/src'
/home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/include/makeinclude/wrapper_macros.GNU:218: /home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/include/makeinclude/platform_macros.GNU: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/include/makeinclude/platform_macros.GNU'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/admin/Desktop/compile/ace/ACE_wrappers/apps/gperf/src'
make: *** [gperf] Error 2
```

I could not find this file "platform_macros.GNU" anywhere in the source tree ? Appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the platform_macros.GNU file, see the free [CORBA Programmers Guide](http://www.remedy.nl/opensource/corbapg.html) chapter 19 for more information how to compile ACE.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. I Added platform_macros.GNU under ACE_wrappers\include\makeinclude.  Contents inside the platform_macros.GNU is                                                                    include $(ACE_ROOT)/include/makeinclude/platform_linux.GNU